# Clearing a SKScene to start a new game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

After my game ends I have a button called play again but when it runs it throws and error saying `Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent`. My question is can I reset or dealloc the SKScene so that it is like a fresh slate, like the app was never run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[self removeAllChildren];` in your SKScene to remove all children nodes.

Other objects like arrays, strings, etc... you will have to deal with on a one to one basis.

You can check if a node already has a parent before adding by doing this:

```
if(myNode.parent == nil)
    [self addChild:myNode];
```

Comment: I tired that in the didMoveToview and I still get the same exception thrown.

Comment: @Big_Mac_24 - You would not run that in didMoveToView. You would use that code in a custom method to 'reset you SKScene' as you indicated in your question. Your error message is generated by attempting to add a node with a parent to another parent.

Comment: It could be a child of a child that is causing an issue. Adding a recursive method to remove children of children might help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code is being executed in your scene I think what you want is this..

```
MyScene *newScene = [[MyScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:newScene];
```

Where MyScene is SKScene subclass.

Hopefully that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I ran that from the didMoveToView and got another error.

Comment: I think I am running into the same issue as @sangony. This is to be executed in the code when your "play again" button is pressed.